# Caliburn.Micro Binding does not seem to resolve in the view model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, caliburn.micro

I have an data transfer object called `Report`. These report objects are held in an observable collection in a different class called `Controller`. What I am trying to do is create a view that takes data from the `Report` and displays that in a list.

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to bind the view properly to the view model. I managed to get it to bind by using a value converter and returning the viewmodel that I need but the Bindings do not seem to resolve even though the view is attached.

The viewmodel that contains the `Report` list:

```
public class ReportListViewModel : Screen, IModule
{
    private Controller _controller;
    public Controller Controller
    {
        get { return _controller; }
        set { _controller = value; }
    }

    public ReportListViewModel(Controller controller)
    {
        Controller = controller;
        Controller.Domain.Reports.Add(new Model.Report() { Notes = "Test Data.." });
    }
}
```

And the XAML view for it:

```
<Grid Background="Blue">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:ReportToListItem x:Key="reportToListItem" />
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <ListBox Height="100" x:Name="Controller_Domain_Reports">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource reportToListItem}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The value converter:

```
internal class ReportToListItem : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var vm = IoC.Get<ReportListItemViewModel>();
        vm.Report = (Report)value;
        var view = ViewLocator.GetOrCreateViewType(typeof(ReportListItemView));
        ViewModelBinder.Bind(vm, view, null);
        return view;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here are the viewmodel and view that are going to be responsible for displaying the data of the `Report` object.

Viewmodel:

```
public class ReportListItemViewModel : Screen
{
    private Report _report;
    public Report Report
    {
        get { return _report; }
        set { _report = value; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Report, Path=Notes}" />
</Grid>
```

Now I know that the view is being attached because the `OnViewAttached` method of the `ReportListItemViewModel` is triggered. I know the view is being initialed too because it's constructor is triggered.

But the getter on the `ReportListItemViewModel.Report` is never called.

So what is going wrong with the Binding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To load the view automatically with caliburn, you have to bind to Caliburn's attached properties:

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding ...}"/>
```

Otherwise you won't load the corresponding view into the content control but the viewmodel itself.

Edit:

The stuff above seems to be nonsense, since the OP says the view gets created, also I think I spotted the actual problem:

If you set the binding like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Report, Path=Notes}" />
```

it won't work, since you are overwriting the path `Report` with `Notes`. To access the `Notes` property in `Report`, you have to specify the item like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Report.Notes}" />
```

or like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Report.Notes}" />
```

Comment: I have implemented your proposed change and changed the value converter to correspond in returning the vm instead of the view (As it was trying to find the view for the view) but the result is still the same. Everything initializes fine but the Binding for `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Report, Path=Notes}" />` never triggers the getter : /

Comment: I was already fixing my mistake when you posted your comment ;)

Comment: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Report.Notes}" />` That did it.. Such an easy thing I overlooked! Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: fwiw your nonsense fixed my problem!